# What does this section of the FAQ mean?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers

> Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask. It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

It's not exactly clear to me what the last sentence means. From how I understand it, users should never report the answer of their own question, if not in the form of a question; in most of the cases, I think that if the user who asked the question would add an answer that sounds like another question, the answer would be probably merged with the original question.

Supposing that a user find the answer to the question s/he posted after week of searching, and before anybody else answered or gave the correct answer, can the OP write an answer reporting what s/he found to be the solution?

Comment: Yeah, I've wondered before how popular Jeopardy! was in other parts of the world. Linking to the Wikipedia article may not be enough to give people who have never heard of the gameshow an intuitive feel for what the sentence is trying to convey.

Comment: @Cody Gray In a Jeopardy, you start with an answer, and people must guess which question would be answered from that answer. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hmm, no, you're right. I suppose even I don't know what Jeopardy is... Or never stopped to really think about it.

Comment: Q:"How do I do XYZ" A:"Why, thanks for asking, me!  Here's exactly how:"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that if you already know the answer to your question you can still post it. You might have just solved a particularly tricky bug and want to share your new knowledge (for example).

So frame your question **as though you haven't solved the problem yet** and then post it. Wait a day or so and then post your answer. Wait another day or so before accepting your answer.

In the meantime you might get other answers that are actually better than yours.

It's up to you whether you indicate that you've already solved the problem or not. My preference is not to do that. You don't want to put people off.

Comment: That is in the case the user already knows the answer before to post the question; what should the OP do, if s/he find the answer after some days (e.g. 7 days, or more) after s/he asked the question?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - exactly the same. Post the answer and then accept it after another day or so.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: If the poster discovers the answer after posting the question, and nobody has posted it in the meantime, it is fine for them to post the answer themselves.

Comment: The thing is, that sentence is not the clearest way to express that. Let's read it again: "It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question." Phrase *it*? What is "it"? If it refers to answering, it's just plain wrong. (Answers must *not* be phrased as questions.) And if it refers to asking, then it's superfluous. (Questions should be phrased as questions? No news to anyone.) Either way, mentioning Jeopardy makes little sense. Even less so in light of Cody Gray's comment above.

Comment: @Reg "it" is the question, and you'd think it's superfluous, but it's in there to try and stop people from posting "questions" that are basically just blog posts explaining how they solved a problem. It's trying to get them to post the question as the question and the answer as the answer