# Bad English from non-native speakers

Tags: discussion, edits, ethics, non-english-speakers

I've been recently coming across questions with poor English; questions that are grammatically incorrect, not properly capitalised and whatnot. What should we do about it? Should we downvote or edit or do nothing because it might hurt/discourage the OP?

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207691/152859) sums my own opinion up as well: if the question can be salvaged, edit it. If not, vote to close it as you would any other bad question.

Comment: Your clause after the semicolon is incomplete. ;)

Comment: Thank you for that @jonsca, I edited own question.

Comment: @Kartagis I was just pulling your chain, don't worry.

Comment: @jonsca no sweat!